# Rails associations clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a basic inventory tracking system. Each User can create an **item** with an optional **location** so that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
end
```

I can't quite get my head around who belongs to who! I know that each item and location must belong to the User. I also want an association so that each item can have one location, but I don't know if it has to be through the User. Am I making sense?

I am having difficulty with my inventory item form where it isn't recognizing any locations and so I think I must have my models set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're doing something where a user would have a location directly, this should be what you need.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :locations, :through => :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_one :user, :through => :items  # Only if you want `Location#user` methods
end
```

An item `belongs_to` a user — that much we can agree on. An item also `belongs_to` a location because, simply, we want the foreign key on the item model so that a multitude of items can be associated with the same location.

You probably don't want locations to be user-specific, so no complementary `has_one :user` association on the location model.

Comment: I think we're getting closer. I do want locations to be user specific I believe. Each user (client) will have their own inventory and locations. For instance, one user may have 50 items. That user may have items stored in "garage", "library" and "moms attic". Another user may have 50 items stored in "Canada", "US" and "China". There's no overlap between users with regard to items or locations. Make sense? I might just be missing what you guys are saying, but I know that locations is User specific...

Comment: Then you can add `has_one :user, :through => :items` on your Location model. You don't need to do this unless you will want to lookup the user from a location (`Location.find(123).user`). By default, if you run `@user.locations` you will only get locations for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Think of belongs_to as a way to specify a foreign key.

Other than that, think in natural language.

```
A user has an inventory
An inventory has items
An item has a location
A user has items through inventory
A user has locations through items(possibly, if you want that)
```

Associations are just a way to get facilities like user.inventory.items or user.locations :)

EDIT

A user-location is a many to many association. That means, that you need a third user_locations table that belongs to user and location. That is unless a location belongs to only one user. Otherwise, if two users and more can have the same location, you need a through user_locations model.

Comment: i was hoping to have a select list of previously entered locations. Does it make sense to have: A user has many locations; location belongs to user; an item has one location? is there any :through there? That's the one that messes me up... the location list should be independent of the items...

Comment: i will reply in my post above.

Comment: replied above, please take a look. I'm pretty sure that you need a third model like user_locations.

Comment: ya. a location belongs to a user. Like where they keep their own private inventory items (think of an artist with their art at their gallery/s). So I now have the location with has_many :items, :through => :user. And item has_many :locations, :through => :user. An item really has only one location, but has_one doesn't seem right to me. I'll see if I can make this work tomorrow.

Comment: If an item belongs to a location, then a location should have many items (and item belongs to location - just that). The location of the item is now given my item.location.

Comment: I disagree with the argument that a many-to-many relationship is needed here, but I want to point out that the join table you incorrectly referenced as a "user_locations model" is A) not a model at all, B) is merely a database table, and C) named in lexical order  (alphabetical, with case and special characters being different) with each model name pluralized…or "users_locations" or "items_locations".

Comment: I think that we all know that user_locations refers to the db table. Yes, UserLocation would typically be the model, duh. Alphabetical order is only important in habtm, pluralize is a mere matter of taste. And i mentioned that it might be a many-many and then julie elaborated on wht that it's not.